# how to click on a button in the iphone application and link to a second page within the app

Tags: iphone, button, sdk, hyperlink

i am building up a view-based project with out a navigation bar. I have 2 pages. Simply need a button to link from page one to page two. Then a button to link from page two to page one. Seems it should be very simple but i am having a heck of a time trying to get it.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction) view2ButtonPressed: (id) sender {
    View2Controller *vc = [[View2Controller alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Then link the touchedUp action of your button to the view2ButtonPressed method. (Make sure you list the method in your .h file as well)

Comment: Don't forget to `[vc release]` after it's pushed to the nav controller or you'll leak memory.